# javascript loop nested array and extract properties based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, mapreduce

I have a `kids` object that looks like the following:

```
const kids = {
    name: 'john',
    extra: {
        city: 'London',
        hobbies: [
            {
                id: 'football',
                team: 'ABC',
            },
            {
                id: 'basketball',
                team: 'DEF',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

and i have the following object that contains all sports and extra info for each.

```
const sports = [
    {
        name: 'volleyball',
        coach: 'tom',
    },
    {
        name: 'waterpolo',
        coach: 'jack',
    },
    {
        name: 'swimming',
        coach: 'kate',
    },
    {
        name: 'football',
        coach: 'sara',
    },
];
```

I want to get the list of all `id`s in the hobbies array and go through each of the sports items in the sports array, and found, add an extra field to that object `available` and give a value of `true`, and **its corresponding team name** too so the result will look like:

```
const result = [
    {
        name: 'volleyball',
        coach: 'tom',
    },
    {
        name: 'waterpolo',
        coach: 'jack',
    },
    {
        name: 'swimming',
        coach: 'kate',
    },
    {
        name: 'football',
        coach: 'sara',
        available: true,   // it exists in kids' hobbies
        team: 'DEF'      // get it from kids' hobbies
    },
];
```

by the way, here is my attempt:

```
const result = kids.extra.hobbies.map(a => a.id);
for (var key in sports) {
    console.log(sports[key].name);
    const foundIndex = result.indexOf(sports[key].name);
    if ( foundIndex > -1) {
      sports[key].available = true;
    }
}
console.log(sports)
```

**But this doesn't include the team. How can I add it to the above code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.find` to find the appropriate hobby object, and then extract its `team` if it exists:

```js
const kids = {name:'john',extra:{city:'London',hobbies:[{id:'football',team:'ABC',},{id:'basketball',team:'DEF',},],},}
const sports = [{name:'volleyball',coach:'tom',},{name:'waterpolo',coach:'jack',},{name:'swimming',coach:'kate',},{name:'football',coach:'sara',},];
const { hobbies } = kids.extra;
const result = sports.map((sportObj) => {
  const foundObj = hobbies.find(({ id }) => id === sportObj.name);
  if (!foundObj) return { ...sportObj };
  return {...sportObj, team: foundObj.team, available: true };
});
console.log(result);
```

Without spread:

```js
const kids = {name:'john',extra:{city:'London',hobbies:[{id:'football',team:'ABC',},{id:'basketball',team:'DEF',},],},}
const sports = [{name:'volleyball',coach:'tom',},{name:'waterpolo',coach:'jack',},{name:'swimming',coach:'kate',},{name:'football',coach:'sara',},];
const { hobbies } = kids.extra;
const result = sports.map((sportObj) => {
  const foundObj = hobbies.find(({ id }) => id === sportObj.name);
  if (!foundObj) return Object.assign({}, sportObj);
  return Object.assign({}, sportObj, { team: foundObj.team, available: true });
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `result` array and `kids.extra.hobbies` have the same array indexes (since one was mapped the other). Therefore you can lookup hobby object with `foundIndex` from the hobbies:

```
const result = kids.extra.hobbies.map(a => a.id);
for (var key in sports) {
    const foundIndex = result.indexOf(sports[key].name);
    if ( foundIndex > -1) {
      sports[key].available = true;
      // lookup hobby at `foundIndex`
      sports[key].team = kids.extra.hobbies[foundIndex].team;
    }
}
console.log(sports)
```